# How to put function into onPressed methon in FAB?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to sort one arrays in two with a specific character inside them. Also I need to put it in the UI thread and then users taps floating action button it return list which contains A or list which contains B.

I was trying just put the sortArray inside `onpressed` merhond inside FAB but it dosen't work.

```
class _ExpState extends State<Exp> {
  final List<CoffeeShop> coffeeShop = <CoffeeShop>[
    CoffeeShop(id: 1, shopTitle: 'Strarbucks A'),
    CoffeeShop(id: 2, shopTitle: 'Dunkin doghnuts B'),
    CoffeeShop(id: 3, shopTitle: 'Subway B'),
    CoffeeShop(id: 4, shopTitle: 'MCCafe A'),
    CoffeeShop(id: 5, shopTitle: 'Coffee Shop B'),
  ];

  List<CoffeeShop> listWithA = [];
  List<CoffeeShop> listWithB = [];

void sortArray() {
setState(() {
coffeeShop.forEach((element) {
  if (element.shopTitle.toUpperCase().contains('A')) {
    listWithA.add(element);
  } else if (element.shopTitle.toUpperCase().contains('B')) {
    listWithB.add(element);
  }
});
});
```

}

```
  @override
  void initState() {
      sortArray();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: coffeeShop.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(coffeeShop[index].shopTitle),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            Exp1(
                                sid: coffeeShop[index].id,
                                shopTitle: coffeeShop[index].shopTitle
                            )));
              },
            );
          }
          ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        if (listWithA.length == null) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: listWithA.length, itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(title: Text(listWithA[index].shopTitle),);
          });
        } else {
          if (listWithB.length == null) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: listWithB.length, itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(title: Text(listWithB[index].shopTitle),);
            });
          }
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep `sortArray();` inside `initState` but remove `setState` from there into your `sortArray()` function.

Comment: Hi @Huthaifa Muayyad Thanks for helping, but I did as you said and it dosen't make any change. My code now is: `List<CoffeeShop> listWithA = [];
  List<CoffeeShop> listWithB = [];
 void sortArray() {
    setState(() {
    coffeeShop.forEach((element) {
      if (element.shopTitle.toUpperCase().contains('A')) {
        listWithA.add(element);
      } else if (element.shopTitle.toUpperCase().contains('B')) {
        listWithB.add(element);
      }
    });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
      sortArray();
    super.initState();
  } `